# Confused displaying Visualization in LWC

Tags: javascript, lightning-web-components, lwc-dom

I'm trying to display a basic visualization in LWC using vis-network.js.

The example I'm trying is [here](https://visjs.github.io/vis-network/examples/network/basicUsage.html)

Here is my code.

**Component.html:**

```
<template>
  <lightning-card title="Sand Samples" icon-name="utility:start">
    <div class="slds-grid slds-wrap slds-grid--pull-padded">
      <div class="myTestClass" lwc:dom="manual"></div>
    </div>
  </lightning-card>
</template>
```

**Component.js**

```
import {
    LightningElement,
    track
} from 'lwc';
import SL from '@salesforce/resourceUrl/vis';
import {
    loadStyle,
    loadScript
} from 'lightning/platformResourceLoader';
import {
    ShowToastEvent
} from 'lightning/platformShowToastEvent';


export default class TestLoadGraphics extends LightningElement {
    network;

    renderedCallback() {

        Promise.all([
            loadScript(this, SL + '/vis-network.min.js'),
            loadStyle(this, SL + '/vis-network.min.css')
        ]).then(success => {
            var container = this.template.querySelector('.myTestClass');
            // create an array with nodes

            var nodes = new vis.DataSet([{
                    id: 1,
                    label: 'Node 1'
                },
                {
                    id: 2,
                    label: 'Node 2'
                },
                {
                    id: 3,
                    label: 'Node 3'
                },
                {
                    id: 4,
                    label: 'Node 4'
                },
                {
                    id: 5,
                    label: 'Node 5'
                }
            ]);

            // create an array with edges
            var edges = new vis.DataSet([{
                    from: 1,
                    to: 3
                },
                {
                    from: 1,
                    to: 2
                },
                {
                    from: 2,
                    to: 4
                },
                {
                    from: 2,
                    to: 5
                },
                {
                    from: 3,
                    to: 3
                }
            ]);
            var data = {
                nodes: nodes,
                edges: edges
            };
            var options = {};


            this.network = new vis.Network(container, data, options);
            // console.log(network);


        }).catch(error => {
            console.log(error);
            this.dispatchEvent(
                new ShowToastEvent({
                    title: 'Error loading ChartJS',
                    message: 'error.message',
                    variant: 'error',
                }),
            );
        })
    }

}
```

when I run this I get the output as

[image]

Though I have the same code used here, I am unable to show the nodes. It's pretty confusing. Please let me know where am I going wrong.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, most third-party libraries aren't ['Lightning Locker'](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/48.0/lwc/security_locker_service) compatible, and will need some modification before you can use them.

There used to be a non-exhaustive list of compatible libraries knocking around, but I'm failing to find it. [This page](https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/developer-relations/2017/02/lockerservice-lightning-container-third-party-libraries-lightning-components.html) has a few examples though, such as jQuery, moment, Chart.js etc.

Comment: Hey Dan thanks for the quick response. I was wondering, if the issue is with Locker service restrictions. Even the edges should not be loading but here in this case, only the nodes seem missing.

Comment: I believe this might be because libraries aren't accepted/ rejected in a boolean manner. Some parts might be behaving as Salesforce likes, and others might be 'misbehaving'. Sorry that I can't provide greater detail - I'm far from an accomplished JS dev and don't fully understand all this 'shadow DOM', must be 'strict' stuff that applies here.